# Ошибка Could not get unknown property 'ClientId'

Tags: android, android-gradle

Скачал проект с GitHub (насколько я знаю, проект рабочий (он есть в Play Market)), часть кода в build.gradle выделяется красным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всплывает окно Project code style setting migration:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе по More Info, получаю информаццию:

```
New project code style settings format in 2017.3
Skip to end of metadata
Created by Rustam Vishnyakov, last modified by Serge Baranov on Oct 02, 2019Go to start of metadata
Intellij IDEA 2017.3 has got new project code style settings format. Now all code style settings are located under <PROJECT_ROOT>/.idea/codeStyles directory with the ultimate intention to support multiple project code styles linked to different scopes. New code style settings format is also cleaner and contains all code style settings properly grouped per language. Some old legacy Java, HTML settings previously stored without any language tag are moved to "JavaCodeStyleSettings", "HTMLCodeStyleSettings" etc. respectively.

The old .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml is imported to two new files: .idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml containing a link to preferred project code style and .idea/codeStyles/Project.xml with code style settings for different languages. The latter is optional and created only if there are non-default settings. If .idea directory is under version control, both files can be added to VCS too. The old codeStyleSettings.xml is kept for backwards compatibility.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/New+project+code+style+settings+format+in+2017.3
```

Также вылезает ошибка:

```
Build file 'D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\OctoDroid-for-GitHub\app\build.gradle' line: 39

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ClientId' for ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=26, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=56, versionName=4.2.2, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:176)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:181)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'ClientId' for ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=26, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=56, versionName=4.2.2, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:134)
    at build_7o7xt9qmzohugv2fk6dyilzaw$_run_closure2$_closure8.doCall(D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\OctoDroid-for-GitHub\app\build.gradle:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.defaultConfig(BaseExtension.java:431)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.defaultConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:382)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:59)
    at build_7o7xt9qmzohugv2fk6dyilzaw$_run_closure2.doCall(D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\OctoDroid-for-GitHub\app\build.gradle:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:83)
    at build_7o7xt9qmzohugv2fk6dyilzaw.run(D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\OctoDroid-for-GitHub\app\build.gradle:27)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
    ... 70 more
```

Код build.gradle:

```
def taskRequests = getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
def isPlaystore = taskRequests.contains("Playstore") || taskRequests.contains("playstore")

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

if (isPlaystore) {
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        playStore
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 56
        versionName "4.2.2"

        buildConfigField 'String', 'CLIENT_ID', ClientId
        buildConfigField 'String', 'CLIENT_SECRET', ClientSecret
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.playStore
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        // includes proprietary libs
        playstore {

        }

        // only foss
        foss {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':github-api')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1@aar'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.pluscubed:recycler-fast-scroll:0.3.2@aar'
    compile('com.vdurmont:emoji-java:3.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module : 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.github.Tunous:MarkdownEdit:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
    playstoreCompile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'
}

def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
}

if (props.containsKey('STORE_FILE')
        && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD')
        && props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS')
        && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
    android.signingConfigs.playStore.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
    android.signingConfigs.playStore.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
    android.signingConfigs.playStore.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
    android.signingConfigs.playStore.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found or incomplete'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
```

Comment: Этот проект очень старый, в нем низкая версия компеляции, и много чего другого, такой проект лучше переписать заново.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка Could not get unknown property 'explorer\_github\_app\_id'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436963/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-could-not-get-unknown-property-explorer-github-app-id)

Comment: У вас в стектрейсе написано, что ошибка в строчке `39` в файле `build.gradle`, неизвестный параметр `ClientId`. Задайте этот параметр в файле `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Часто бывает, что проект старый(Buratino Apps тоже ссылается на это), то можно создать пустой проект и со старого проекта перекинуть папку src. Если используете Windows, то можно через проводник открыть проект и перекинуть данный файл. И затем надо будет запустить проект и добавить нужные библиотеки, и может быть, выполнить другие манипуляции.
P.s. На моей практике я добавлял только библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Cтектрейс ошибки указывает на неизвестный параметр `ClientId`:

```java
MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'ClientId'
```

Чтобы исправить ошибку, задайте `ClientId` и `ClientSecret` в файле `gradle.properties`:

```java
ClientId=foo
ClientSecret=bar
```

Укажите вместо `foo` и `bar` необходимые значения.