# Ошибка Could not get unknown property 'explorer_github_app_id'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

При сборке проекта возникает ошибка в строке:

```
buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id)
```

**Стектрейс ошибки:**

```
Build file 'D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\explorer-github\app\build.gradle' line: 30

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'explorer_github_app_id' for BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    ...
```

**Файл build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

ext {
    libs_ver = "28.0.0"
    retrofit_ver = "2.5.0"
    picasso_ver = "2.71828"
    gson_ver = "2.8.5"
    room_ver = "1.1.1"
    lifecycle_ver = "1.1.1"
    dagger_ver = "2.20"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hbvhuwe.explorergithub"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName "1.2.2"
        versionCode 120002
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id)
            resValue("string", "application_client_id", explorer_github_app_id)

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientSecret", explorer_github_app_secret)
            resValue("string", "application_client_secret", explorer_github_app_secret)
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id)
            resValue("string", "application_client_id", explorer_github_app_id)

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientSecret", explorer_github_app_secret)
            resValue("string", "application_client_secret", explorer_github_app_secret)
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.1'
    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_ver"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_ver"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    //Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
    //Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_ver"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_ver"
    //Picasso
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picasso_ver"
    //Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_ver"
    //support library
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
    //JUnit
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Kotlin в проекте: 1.7.10
Kotlin в Android Studio: [212-1.7.10-release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6zz8.png)
Gradle wrapper: [7.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXp94.png)
Android gradle plugin: [7.0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXp94.png)

Comment: Переменная `explorer_github_app_id` и подобные вообще хоть где-то определены? Что у Вас в классе `BuildConfig`?

Comment: пока что не получается найти BuildConfig в проекте, подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому пути он должен находиться

Comment: Найдите в проекте, где определяется `explorer_github_app_id`? Если эта переменная нигде не определена, то в этом и заключается ошибка. Нужно задать переменной какое-то значение. Что касается BuildConfig, то этот класс генерируется во время сборки. Если не было успешной сборки, то этого класса может не быть. (А так он должен находиться где-то здесь app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/hbvhuwe/explorergithub/BuildConfig.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте в файле `gradle.properties` (в корне вашего проекта) недостающие параметры:

```
explorer_github_app_id=foo
explorer_github_app_secret=bar
```

Есть и другой способ, эти параметры можно передавать при запуске из командной строки:

```bash
./gradlew -Pexplorer_github_app_id=foo -Pexplorer_github_app_secret=bar
```

Подробнее о gradle properties есть [на сайте gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

Не забудьте задать вместо `foo` и `bar` правильные значения.

Comment: а откуда брать эти правильные значения, которые вместо foo и bar?

Comment: Вам должно быть виднее, посмотрите как в коде используются константы `BuildConfig.applicationClientId` и `BuildConfig.applicationClientSecret` (a также `R.string.application_client_id` и `R.string.application_client_secret`). Судя по названию попробую догадаться, что это какие-то данные для авторизации на Github. Если ваше приложение делает запросы к Github через REST, то вся [документация тут](https://docs.github.com/rest).